# How to make XY to Line dynamic to access query?

Tags: line, table, ms-access, dynamic, xy

I have connected the Access file to the ArcGIS file, and displayed it using the tool XY to line, but when I change the access file, this is not automatically adjusted in the ArcGIS template. Somehow, ArcGIS makes the XY line static, so it does not have the possibility to change.

What should I do to make the produced lines 'dynamic'?

Answer (score 1):

The XY to Line tool creates a new file (feature class or shapefile) which contains the lines. This means that what you are seeing in ArcMap isn't really coming from your Access file.

You are looking at a file that was created from the original access file. You might be able to use model builder to recreate your lines and overwrite the previous line file.

- Sorry if this sounds confusing, I've tried to simplify things as much as possible.